# How to disable generate css code after use tab - sublime and emmet

Tags: sublimetext, emmet

Since few years i use SB + emmet.
Almost everyday i'm using auto generate tags, when i type "script" and click tab emment generate beauty "" tag.
From few days after generate tag after put TAB on my closet automaticly emmet put "script {

}"
It's sooooooo fcking anoying. For example when i have want to expand img tag and after it i want paste url to image.

I want to remove functionality generating nametag + brackets after put tab.

For explain i made video with my problem (sorry for voice from conference ) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYw6uLS19WM Can You help me?

Comment: From your video I can see you’ve pasted something info `src` attribute and it was replaced with something bad. Emmet doesn’t override any copy/paste features so you should check other plugins

Comment: Yea, it was "Emmet CSS Snippets" i removed it and now is good. It was seriously anoying...

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this:

For me removing the package "emmet scss style reflector" (or slightly different name) did the job